# Multiple include paths (-I) for g++ in Eclipse and MinGW

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, opencv, libxml2

I am using Eclipse Luna in a Windows environment to write programs in C++. I compile with MinGW. I am also using OpenCV and libxml2.

My programs get compiled with these include paths:

```
g++ "-IC:\\MinGW\\include\\libxml2" ...
```

However, I need include paths for `libxml`, so what I want is:

```
g++ "-IC:\\MinGW\\include\\ibxml2" "-IC:\\opencv\\build\\include"
```

I tried to set this up under "*project | Propterities | Tool Settings | GCC C++ Compiler*" in the project properties:

```
-I"C:\opencv\build\include" -I"C:\MinGW\include\libxml2" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -v
```

However, it only puts the first one in the actual compile command, according to the console.

It does work *sometimes*, though:

- If I "Clean" the project and the build it, it will build without errors and even run from Windows Explorer or a prompt.
- If I try to Run or Debug it from Eclipse, it will fail and have the problems described above.
- If I "Clean" it and Run or Debug it, it will run fine in the Debug perspective, but will terminate without warning.